# How to stop Chrome from displaying dialog to print screen

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

I'm making an app with Onsen UI and I'm having some trouble with trying too run the code itself. Chrome always displays a dialog to print the screen, which I don't want to do, and when I click cancel, the whole tab freezes and I have to open a new one only for the same problem to occur again. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my JavaScript or HTML code:

**JavaScript & HTML Code**

```js
const selectTagM = document.getElementById("Month");
    const months = selectTagM.options;
    var selectedMonth = months[selectTagM.selectedIndex].value;
```

```html
<ons-select id="Month" onchange="editSelects()">
                        <option value="January">January</option>
                        <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
                        <option value="March">March</option>
                        <option value="April">April</option>
                        <option value="May">May</option>
                        <option value="June">June</option>
                        <option value="July">July</option>
                        <option value="August">August</option>
                        <option value="September">September</option>
                        <option value="October">October</option>
                        <option value="November">November</option>
                        <option value="December">December</option>
                </ons-select>
```

I keep on getting this problem and it prevents me from running the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: The code you included doesn't actually cause the error though

Comment: Not your problem, but it’s much simpler to do`selectedMonth = selectTagM.value`. ;-)

Comment: Glad to know that it's not because of my code, I guess it's just a glitch with Chrome? Also, thanks for suggesting he code change, that will be useful in the future!